# Writing a new R file and saving it to a directory by using code

Tags: r

I would like to write a code in an existing R file that I am working in so that my code when executed creates a new blank  source R file and saves this source file to a specific directory. Also I would like to write a set of commands like

1. flag <- runif(100)
2. print(flag)
   which should be written onto the blank r file when executed from the R file that I am working in. The execution of my code from my current R file  should only write these commands onto the new source R file  and not produce any results. Finally I need to write a code that would read all these commands from the source R file and execute in my current R file to produce the results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
writeLines("# This is a blank file", "RunCode.R")  # Create a file
fle <- file("RunCode.R", "at")                     # Open the file to append
cat("flag <- runif(100)\n", file=fle)              # Write first line
cat("print(flag)\n", file=fle)                     # Write second line
close(fle)                                         # Close the file
source("RunCode.R", echo=TRUE)                     # Run file, echo lines

# > # This is a blank file
# > flag <- runif(100)
# 
# > print(flag)
#   [1] 0.0511489948 0.0821812695 0.3730552096 . . . 
#   . . .
#  [99] 0.3611261339 0.2739890448
ls()                                        # flag object now exists
#  [1] "flag"
```